# Show local notification every hour

Tags: ios4

I am new to Iphone programming. I was able to get local notification code from net. Now i want this to launch after every one hour. I did tried changing different values. However notification is shown only once. Please help.

Comment: It's very difficult to see what's wrong with your code when you don't show us what you've tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use repeatInterval property of UILocalNotification class.

see [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Your link is down.